Unable to migrate local tables to heroku postgres
Running flask db upgrade on ⬢ project312-staging... up, run.1015 INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl. INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL. ERROR [flask_migrate] Error: Can't locate revision identified by '684f15cb35d8'
When I try and run flask db upgrade I get the following error
I was expecting my local tables to be deployed to heroku

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
